# QWidget/QPainter show() + paintEvent() -> shows rectangle on old position

Tags: qt, transparent, qwidget, paintevent

I have to show rectangles at different positions on a transparent Qt window.
Before showing the window i set the new rectangle position. Sometimes the old position is shown for a few milliseconds. (for example m_y_pos=100 instead of m_y_pos=400). It seems there is kind of a race condition between showing the window and updating the window.

I hope somebody know a suggestion.

Thanks pulp

Example Code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>

class QtGuiApplication : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  int m_x_pos;
  int m_y_pos;
  QTimer* m_timer;

  QtGuiApplication(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QMainWindow(parent), m_x_pos(100), m_y_pos(100)
  {
    setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000);

    //Make Window transparent
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus);

    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    m_timer->setInterval(500);
    m_timer->start();
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &QtGuiApplication::Tick);
  }

  private slots:

  //toggle visibility of the window to show the effect
  void Tick()
  {
    if (isVisible())
    {
      hide();
    }
    else
    {
      //Set new position before showing the window
      m_y_pos = m_y_pos == 100 ? 400 : 100;
      show();
    }
  }

  //Paint rectangles at different positions
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
  {
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);

    for (int i = 0; i < event->rect().width(); i += 50)
    {
      painter.drawRect(m_x_pos + i, m_y_pos, 30, 30);
    }
  }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QtGuiApplication w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue here, but in general you should inform the paint system that your widget needs to be updated by calling `update()` whenever parameters change that change the appearance of your widget. (I.e. in your case directly after setting `m_y_pos` in `Tick()`)

Comment: Behavior is only reproducable under Windows 7 with Aero enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You lack the call to `update()` after changing the position. Usually, this should be factored out to a `setPos` method.

Once you do that, the `hide()` and `show()` are not necessary anymore: each `setPos` invocation will update the widget as needed.

You should be deriving from the most basic class that fulfills your needs: `QWidget`. You're not using any functionality of `QMainWindow`, after all.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/rect-paint-42194052
#include <QtWidgets>

class Window : public QWidget
{
   QPointF m_pos{100, 100};
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override
   {
      QPainter painter(this);
      painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
      painter.setPen(Qt::black);
      for (int i = 0; i < event->rect().width(); i += 50)
         painter.drawRect(QRectF(m_pos.x() + i, m_pos.y(), 30, 30));
   }
public:
   Window(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent)
   {
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
      setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
      setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
                     | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus);
   }
   void setPos(const QPointF & pos) {
      m_pos = pos;
      update();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Window w;
   QTimer timer;
   QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&w]{
      static bool toggle{};
      if (!w.isVisible()) {
         toggle = !toggle;
         if (toggle)
            w.setPos({200, 200});
         else
            w.setPos({100, 100});
      };
      w.setVisible(!w.isVisible());
   });
   timer.start(500);
   w.resize(1000, 500);
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. i tested it: the effect is still there (Windows 7, Aero enabled) possible because update() has no effect if the windows is not visible. at the moment i use a workaround: i move the window of the screen instead of hiding it. (yes bad...)

Comment: Then it's a Qt bug.